# В цикле выдаются makeText( getApplicationContext(), … , ... ).show(). Но почему-то вывод на экран внезапно прекращается!

Tags: android

В цикле выдаются makeText(getApplicationContext(), … , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

```
 for ( int i=0; i<100; i++ ) {
       ...
       ...
       ...
       makeText(getApplicationContext(), st1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
       makeText(getApplicationContext(), st2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
       makeText(getApplicationContext(), st3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show(); 
 }
```

Но почему-то вывод на экран после, примерно, пятнадцатого вывода makeText(..) внезапно прекращается. Полностью! Без всяких предупреждений!

Почему такое происходит? Не хватает памяти?

Как решить эту проблему?

P.S. Переменные st1, st2, st3 - нормально формируются и в момент прекращения вывода на экран имеют нормальные реальные (не нулевые, не пустые) строковые значения

Comment: вы создали два одинаковых вопроса. может один удалите? ну и да - приведите полный код

Comment: Уважаемый Алексей! Пожалуйста, перечитайте мои вопросы... Они разные. Один - как остановить вывод Toast в цикле..., другой - прерываются внезапно выводы Toast (памяти  девайсу может не хватает). На эти оба вопроса я давно не могу найти ответы. (Да, они оба связаны с Toast и очень важные для меня)

Comment: Понятно. Но вопросы описаны неясно. Добавьте больше информации в них. Больше кода, которые демонстрируют проблему.

Comment: Хорошо! Я так и сделаю, только чуть позже, в дан. момент занят. )